# Scriptella encoding issue in migrating utf-8 data from access (mdb) to Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, ms-access, character-encoding, scriptella

I wrote program using java and scriptella(etl framework) to move data from access(mdb) to oracle, I changed the unicodeCompression in Access for each field to YES and I'v tested oracle encoding by adding utf-8 data in SqlDeveloper which is ok,Now when I run the program to move the data to Oracle I got questionMarks in records.

here is my etl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <connection id="dbInput"  url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$MDB_FILE_NAME" />
    <connection id="dbOutput"  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" user="user"    password="pass" />
    <query connection-id="dbInput" >
        SELECT * FROM table1;
        <script connection-id="dbOutput"> 
            INSERT INTO some_table(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) values (?field1,
            ?field2, ?field3);
        </script>
    </query>
</etl>
```

What's wrong with that?

I'v seen input/output encoding in ETL tools such as jasperETL , is there something like that in scriptella ?

[image: Access data]
[image: moved data in oracle , the last one(id=4) I filled in SqlDeveloper]
moved data in oracle , the last one(id=4) I filled it directly in SqlDeveloper

Comment: I did the same process except moving data from access to access and the result is the same !

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the charSet property [introduced in Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/bridge.html):

```
<connection id="dbInput"  url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$MDB_FILE_NAME">
    charSet=UTF-8
</connection>
```

Comment: Can you try charSet=Cp1097 or charSet=Cp1098. These are single-byte encodings IBM Iran (Farsi)/Persian (PC).